# htmlentities and é (e acute)

Tags: php, character-encoding, html-entities

I'm having a problem with PHP's `htmlentities` and the é character. I know it's some sort of encoding issue I'm just overlooking, so hopefully someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

Running a straight `htmlentities("é")` does not return the correct code as expected (either `&#233;` or `&eacute;`. I've tried forced the charset to be 'UTF-8' (using the charset parameter of htmlentities) but the same thing.

The ultimate goal is to have this character sent in an HTML email encoded in 'ISO-8859-1'. When I try to force it into that encoding, same issue. In the source of the email, you see é, and in the HTML view `Ã©`.

Who can shed some light on my mistake?

Comment: Try calling `get_html_translation_table()` and looking at the resulting array.  This will tell you whether your e-acute should be translated.  If this doesn't work, you can always get this table, add e-acute to it and then use `strtr($string, $table)` to do the encoding.

Comment: Make sure your file is encoded in UTF-8, and make sure you have the <meta> encoding character correctly set.

Comment: If you set your site encoding to UTF-8 (using either the `<meta>` tag or http headers, you won't need to entity encode accented characters at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
// I assume that your page is utf-8 encoded
header("Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");

$in_utf8encoded = "é à ù è ò";

// first you need the convert the string to the charset you want...
$in_iso8859encoded = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $in_utf8encoded);

// ...in order to make htmlentities work with the same charset
$out_iso8859= htmlentities($in_iso8859encoded, ENT_COMPAT, "ISO-8859-1");

// then only to display in your page, revert it back to utf-8
echo iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $out_iso8859);
```

Comment: Thank you! `iconv` fixed my email encoding issue.

Comment: Adding the encoding is key here - especially if htmlentities worked for you before, and broke. The PHP team had the ingenious idea to not just change the *defaults* to htmlentities once, but twice. Before 5.4, it was ISO-8859-1. After 5.4 and before 5.6 it was UTF-8. As of 5.6, it's whatever the default_charset setting in your php.ini says. Once you specify the encoding, it'll work again, no htmlspecialchars needed. Keep that in mind if you suddenly lost data because you relied on the documented (!) defaults not changing. PHP is always full of surprises - and not in a good way.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at http://php.net/html_entity_decode . You can use this in the following way:

```
$eacute = html_entity_decode('&eacute;',ENT_COMPAT,'iso-8859-1');
```

This way you don't have to care about the encoding of the php file.
edit: typo

Comment: I'm not trying to decode, I'm trying to encode. Please read the question before posting.

Answer (score 2):

I have added htmlspecialchars for you to see that it is really encoded

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/11ce7/4

```
<?PHP
echo htmlspecialchars(htmlentities("é", ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with

```
$string = htmlentities($string,ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE,"ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score -4):

If you have stored the special characters as é, then you could use the following soon after making connection to the `database`.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $dbHandler);
```

With this, you now don't need to use `htmlentities` while displaying data.

Comment: I don't remember saying anything about a database.

Comment: I know, but I am suggestion something that worked with me under the same situation as yours. Using this way, it will encode everything while pulling from database and would avoid using other php functions like `htmlentities`, `html_entity_decode`, `html_entity_encode` etc

Comment: My situation does not involve a database in any way, shape, or form. Thus the reason a database was not mentioned in the OP. Please read before posting in haste.