# How to Encode and Decode "Acute accented characters" using Perl

Tags: html, mysql, perl, template-toolkit

I am working in a web based educational website, where we are using Perl, MySQL 5, Apache and Template Toolkit. we are planning to introduce the support for multiple\ Language in our website.

What we have done in

IF we have a Tab name like Courses Main Page<\h1> in our template file, we have converted that to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<h1>[% glossary.$language.courses_main_page %]<\h1>
```

where $language is getting the value which user selects when he logs in.

We have a table to maintain this data in our Mysql DB:

> CREATE TABLE `translation` (   `english` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `language` varchar(255) NOT NULL,   `translation` varchar(2000) NOT
>   NULL, ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Translation of
>   Element text to a foreign language'

[image]

IN the connect function of MySQL, I am providing 'SET character_set_results=NULL'.
I tried with utf8, but the issue which is limited to some tabs got increased to many sections.

So as soon as the user logins into the system, we fetch all the translation and store it in a PERL hash and Cache it. we pass this hash to template file which will replace the value.

Problem: Acute accented characters like á and é etc are getting replaced with some different character set symbols.

For ex: in Front end we are seeing "Cursos PÃ¡gina Principal" for Cursos Página Principal.

It is very similar to the solution given in [htmlentities and é (e acute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663738/htmlentities-and-e-e-acute)

Can any one tell me how to achieve the same in Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Denoting the charset

> For ex: in Front end we are seeing "Cursos PÃ¡gina Principal" for Cursos Página Principal.

This [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) happens when the characters are transferred as UTF-8 but interpreted as ISO-8859-1 or similar. So I suggest the easiest way to fix this is making sure that your HTML page gets shipped to the client with a proper mime type, i.e.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

If that information is present in the HTML header, the value there will override any setting in the HTML document itself. So make sure that either you set the HTML header, or that your HTML header specifies no charset at all, so that the browser will have a look at the meta setting.

In some browsers (Firefox for example) you can manually change the character set using View / Character Encoding. You can use that to check whether a wrong character encoding while rendering really is the cause of the problem.

## Actually encoding and decoding

There are some situations where fixing the charset won't help. It might be that you simply don't control that part of your framework. Or that something translates your characters from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 *twice*, so that the unreadable symbols are in fact represented as UTF-8 already. In these cases, you can use the [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Encode/Encode.pm) module to encode the characters in Perl directly, using HTML character references as output:

```
use Encode qw(decode encode FB_HTMLCREF);
# maybe: $unicodeString = decode("utf-8", $byteString);
$htmlString = encode("ascii", $unicodeString, FB_HTMLCREF);
```

Whether or not the `decode` step is neccessary depends on how you talk to your database. If your database connection is capable of supporting unicode, then you'll already have unicode strings, and you can simply encode these to HTML. For [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/) there is a parameter `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1` which achieves this. Using it is preferable to decoding things in your own code. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13156138/1468366) has details on the syntax.

One example on what these functions do:

```
$byteString    = "Cursos P\xc3\xa1gina Principal.";   # two bytes
$unicodeString = "Cursos P\N{U+00E1}gina Principal."; # one unicode character
$htmlString    = "Cursos P&#225;gina Principal.";     # html character reference
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. It worked. I didn't needed the Decode step as the Db is handling that. I see some of the place which are still unreadable. "All Current Terms" should be shown as "Todos los términos actuales" but is appearing as "Todos los t&#233;rminos actuales". I am debugging it now. charset=utf-8 is not working for me. It re-introduces the problem.

Comment: There might be a problem with reading data from database and marking it as utf8 (e.g. via `:encoding(utf-8)` layer); I think it is better that running encode by hand.

Comment: @JakubNarębski: I agree. This looks like someone along the path was encoding things over again. Which makes sense in cases where the input might contain characters that have to be encoded for HTML. If this only affects some texts, that's an indication that texts are passed along different paths. Getting rid of those differences might help finding a solution that fits all occurrences: either always pass HTML bytes, or always pass unicode strings, or allways pass UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: @user1254174: Please note the above comments. Too bad [I couldn't notify both of you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85771/188688) in my previous comment.